# Player and Block classes communicating with my World class?

Tags: python, class, oop, object, python-3.x

I'm creating a simple 2D console game, here are my current classes:

```
class World(list):
    def __init__(self, data=(), players=None):
        super().__init__(data)
        self.players = players or []

    def print(self):
        for y in range(len(self)):
            line = ''
            for x in range(len(self[y])):
                for player in self.players:
                    if player.x == x and player.y == y: 
                        line += player.char
                        break
                else:
                    line += self[y][x]
            print(line)

class Block:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, char=' ', solid=False):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.char = char
        self.solid = solid

class Player(Block):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, char='i', solid=True):
        super().__init__(x, y, char, solid)

    def move_up(self):
        pass  # What do I do here?
```

I have no idea how to make it so that my player knows how to communicate with the world to see if the block above him a) exists b) is not solid?
I'm really new to OOP.

**Edit:**
How I'd use the game:

```
my_world = World([
    Block(0, 0, 'x', True), Block(1, 0, 'x', True), Block(2, 0, 'x', True),
    Block(0, 1, 'x', True), Block(1, 1), Block(2, 1, 'x', True),
    Block(0, 2, 'x', True), Block(1, 2), Block(2, 2, 'x', True),
    Block(0, 3, 'x', True), Block(1, 3, 'x', True), Block(2, 3, 'x', True)
])
my_world.players.append(Player(1, 1, 'i'))
```

To create a world like this:

```
xxx
xix
x x
xxx
```

Where player could only move up and down by one block.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way for player to know how to communicate with their world would be to store it in each of them by adding a new attribute to the class. That way instances can access the world they belong to through it.

Another alternative would be to just pass the world as an argument to the player's move methods when they're called.

I had to fix several problems with the code in your question, but what's below appears to work properly.

```
class World(list):
    def __init__(self, data=(), players=None):
        super().__init__(data)
        self.players = players or []

    def print(self):
        for y in range(len(self)):
            line = '  '
            for x in range(len(self[y])):
                for player in self.players:
                    if player.x == x and player.y == y:
                        line += player.char
                        break
                else:
                    line += self[y][x].char
            print(line)

class Block:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, char=' ', solid=False):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.char = char
        self.solid = solid

class Player(Block):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, char='i', solid=True, world=None):
        super().__init__(x, y, char, solid)
        self.world = world

    def move_down(self):
        if self.world is None:
            raise ValueError("Can't move player that has no world")
        x, y = self.x, self.y
        if self.world[y+1][x].solid:
            pass  # Ignore, can't move into solid position.
        else:
            self.world[y][x] = Block(x, y)  # Replace ref in attached world.
            self.world[y+1][x] = self
            self.y += 1  # Update position.
```

And here's code exercising the revised classes:

```
my_world = World([
    [Block(0, 0, 'x', True), Block(1, 0, 'x', True), Block(2, 0, 'x', True)],
    [Block(0, 1, 'x', True), Block(1, 1),            Block(2, 1, 'x', True)],
    [Block(0, 2, 'x', True), Block(1, 2),            Block(2, 2, 'x', True)],
    [Block(0, 3, 'x', True), Block(1, 3, 'x', True), Block(2, 3, 'x', True)]
])
player1 = Player(1, 1, 'i', world=my_world)
my_world.players.append(player1)
print("Before:")
my_world.print()
print()
print("After:")
player1.move_down()
my_world.print()
```

Output:

```
Before:
  xxx
  xix
  x x
  xxx

After:
  xxx
  x x
  xix
  xxx
```

Comment: My teacher said this is a very bad way of doing this, since `Player` class knows `World` class and `World` class knows `Player` class. He didn't give me an other solution though, and told me we'd go through it later on... So not sure what to think

Comment: Yes, as I said in my answer, this was just a simple way of doing it and suggested another alternative. Generally it's best if objects don't know about their container classes. It's known as [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) and should be avoided or minimized whenever possible for the best code.